# Parameter Missing from frontend request to backend

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ecmascript-6, strong-parameters

I am currently getting this error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: first_name
```

I am trying to create a User record with my Rails backend API. I am filtering requests with strong params like so

```
def create
  user = User.new(user_params)
  ...
end

def user_params
  params.require([:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password])
end
```

In my frontend I am making this type of request. I double checked to make sure with the snipper below, the object I am attempting to send is like so:

data:

```
{
  "first_name": "asdasd",
  "last_name": "asdasd",
  "email": "asdasd@gmail.com",
  "password": "password"
}
```

snippet:

```
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      first_name,
      last_name,
      email,
      password,
    }),
  });
```

Comment: did you open your developer tools and checked if the values are being send? F12, then go to network tab, and go to `Headers` and then down to request payload

Comment: @Ifaruki yup request payload looks as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey code looks good to me, however I would try to to define the content type json with property headers

```
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      first_name,
      last_name,
      email,
      password,
    }),
  });
```

I'm not super familiar with fetch yet but often there is black magic that operates when you specify the content type

Comment: That made a difference! Getting a 500 now with https://dpaste.org/qdrQ I think it is the way I am using strong parameters because I assumed passing in an array meant multiple required keys within a hash